# How to combine multiple phpunit extensions (selenium + database)?

Tags: php, database, selenium, phpunit, multiple-inheritance

I have a phpunit setup to test a web page.
On that page, normal users can click on a button and the page does insert some data in a mysql database.

I can use PHPUnit/Selenium extension to auto generate a user click on a button:

```
<?php
class ResourceAgentITest extends PHPUnit_Extensions_SeleniumTestCase
...
?>
```

But I want to validate also the database entries with PHPUnit/Database extension.

```
<?php
class ResourceAgentITest extends PHPUnit_Extensions_Database_TestCase
?>
```

So, on the same test case, I can click on a button, check the database info, check the UI result.

How can I do this since php doesn't support multiple inheritance.

Answer (score 0):

In PHP you can not extend from 2 classes at the same time (no multiple inheritance supported), so the short answer is that you can't do what you want.

In this case I'd extend PHPUnit_Extensions_SeleniumTestCase and access the DB by using your usual production code.